# Parse a list of multiple ip addresses into individual variables

Tags: python, regex, bash, ansible

Is there anyway of parsing an output which I am pulling from stdout.

```
name: PARSE ALL IP's
set fact: parsedbgpIPs="BGPOUTPUT.stdout[0] | regex_findall('\\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b') }}"
```

this produces the output of a list of IP addresses from my original command.

```
10.1.1.1
10.2.2.2
10.3.3.3
```

My question is how to a separate the output into 3 IP addresses each stored as an individual variable?

Comment: `mystring.split()`? If the output is already a list then they're already seperate

Comment: Post "debug: var=BGPOUTPUT" to see the options.

Comment: This is running in ansible so the output is slightly different

Comment: TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Router01] =>
  msg: |-
    List of IP's - 10.1.1.1
    - 10.2.2.2
    - 10.3.3.3

Comment: - debug:
          msg: "List of IP's {{ parsedbgpIPs | to_nice_yaml }}"

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *How to separate the output into 3 IP addresses each stored as an individual variable?*

A: It's possible to create a custom dictionary and create the variables dynamically there. For example the play below

```
  vars:
    my_vars: {}
    my_ip_list:
      - 10.1.1.1
      - 10.2.2.2
      - 10.3.3.3
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_vars: "{{ my_vars|combine({'IP_' ~ my_idx : item}) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_ip_list }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
    - debug:
        var: my_vars
    - debug:
        var: my_vars.IP_1
```

gives

```
"my_vars": {
    "IP_0": "10.1.1.1", 
    "IP_1": "10.2.2.2", 
    "IP_2": "10.3.3.3"
}

"my_vars.IP_1": "10.2.2.2"
```

In your case, it's possible to iterate the list of IPs. Replace *`loop: "{{ my_ip_list }}"`* in the play above with the following line

```
loop: "{{  BGPOUTPUT.stdout[0] | regex_findall('\\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b') }}"
```

Comment: Many thanks, with a fresh head this is working this morning. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

If you store the result of your script in a bash variable, then you can fill an array line by line, with this syntax

```
declare -a IPLIST           # optional but nice
IPLIST=($RESULTOFSCRIPT)    # RESULTOFSCRIPT contains the output of your script
```

Now you can access elements of the newly created array by index

```
echo "${IPLIST[0]}"
10.1.1.1

echo "${IPLIST[1]}"
10.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to parse the output into a text file and then read the file in loop and use that as value of the variable. Below is an example:

```
name: PARSE ALL IP's
set fact: parsedbgpIPs="BGPOUTPUT.stdout[0] | regex_findall('\\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b') }}" > iplist.txt
for ip in $(cat iplist.txt)
do 
   ... (your code)
done
```